# When does each event occur in WinForms

Tags: winforms, events

As I am trying to make my own custom "WinForms", I am left confused on when does each mouse event occurs. I have made my own custom classes, but now the events are something I have to rework, as they won't work right.

I have a custom class for controls. Objects from that class can contain other controls, which can contain other controls and so on. There is a main control, which gets input from a picture box. That input is what is where the mouse is and what even has been activated in the picture box.

So far I have figured, that `MouseMove`, `MouseHover` and `MouseDown` events are the simplest to write, as they occur in simple conditions. But the rest require additional data about the mouse's location, state and past. `MouseDoubleClick` seems to activate after a specific sequence of events (strictly `down-up-down-up`, `down-up-down-move-up` and `down-up-down-move-leave-enter-move-up`, with the movement events not activating). With that in mind, I am even more confused.

In what conditions and sequences does each mouse event occur?

EDIT

Further testing made things even more confusing. For one, now I want to know at what rate is the `MouseMove` being registered, and testing it shows that between each event there is a different time (or so does my use of a `StopWatch` say). This is important, because then that raises the question when is `Hover` being triggered.
`Click` is `down-up`, where moving is allowed between the two.
`DoubleClick` proved to be simple enough - `down-up-down-up`, where moving is allowed explicitly only between the second down-up.
`Hover` activates only once after each `Enter`, when the mouse remains stationary; if you want to trigger `Hover` again, the mouse has to leave and then re-enter.

So the question now is how the system tracks the mouse's activity - how does it detect the mouse moving, being held down and being released. Hopefully that would help me get the full answer.

Comment: Do you really want us write MSDN documentation here? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/mouse-events-in-windows-forms]

Comment: @T.S. Your link is malformed. It should be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/mouse-events-in-windows-forms

Comment: I have tested what events get activated on a click and double click. But I think the link may lead me to something useful.
I am asking on conditions for activation.

Comment: Create a Windows Forms application, attach each event you're interested in to an event handler, `Debug.WriteLine` it's name, and find out how Windows Forms behaves.

Comment: Doing that right now. That is some odd behavior, as 'double click' works in a really strict way - the time between the first 'down' and 'up' is also a factor - hold the mouse down for the first 'click' for too long and 'double click' will not activate, even though 'click' would.
My best bet so far is to keep a history of the mouse's events and let the controls read through that to see if an event in the picture box should activate the respected event in the control in question.

Comment: Why do you need to know all of this?

Comment: Moving the mouse simply sets an internal flag in the native window, indicating that the mouse position has changed.  If your program goes idle and re-enters the dispatcher loop, and no other sent messages need to be handled first, then you get the mouse move message.  So moving the mouse can never overwhelm the UI thread, you get them as fast your code allows.